# Why ngb-tabset resets to first tab when display is hidden and shown?

Tags: html, css, angular, ng-bootstrap

I use ngb-tabset in a component which is under a single **div** section. This div tag is displayed based on a condition to be true. When the condition is false, a different section is displayed.

```html
<div *ngIf="showAllTabs">
  <ngb-tabset>
    <ngb-tab id="heading-1">
      <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
         <div>HEADING 1</div>
      </ng-template>
   </ngb-tab>
 
   <ngb-tab id="heading-2">
      <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
         <div>HEADING 2</div>
      </ng-template>
   </ngb-tab>
  </ngb-tabset>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!showAllTabs">
  <!-- Some other work -->
</div>
```

The issue is, if for instance,the active tab is "heading-2", and when the division tag is hidden and shown again, the active tab is set to the first tab (heading-1) automatically. How to not allow this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was because of the structural directive "**ngIf**". ngIf removes the elements from the DOM and so, when the ngIf turns out to be true, the elements are rendered newly which causes the default tab to be made visible. This can be solved by programming the tab selection by storing the id of the tab in a variable and enabling it each time the DOM elements are rendered back.